cloud functions showing wrong behavior
I have two cloud functions doing some simple book keeping work.
handleUserIn keeps a trace of a user logging in and handleUserOut keeps a trace of a user logging out.
Below is the code for the two functions:
import {onRequest} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp();

exports.handleUserIn = onRequest(
  {cors: ["*"]},
  (request, response) => {
    const userId = request.params[0];
    handleUserTrace(userId, "Log-In");
    // response.send(0); // Wrong.
    response.status(200).send("All seems OK.");
  }); /* End of handleUserIn */


export const handleUserOut = onRequest({cors: ["*"]}, (request, response) => {
  response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
  const userId = request.params[0];
  // corsHandler(request, response, async () => {
  handleUserTrace(userId, "Log-Out");
  // response.send(0); // Wrong.
  response.status(200).send("All seems OK.");
  // }); // End corsHandler.
}); /* End of handleUserOut */

Now comes my question. Though the two functions both do their jobs as expected, when I test them; I get some annoying messages in the developer console of my web browser.
Like the one below:
GET
https://handleuserout-vzu8tf4c5q-uc.a.run.app/xyxCIPDXZXgiR6DsjWx3yFOuXYZ4
[HTTP/2 500  365ms]

GET
    https://handleuserout-vzu8tf4c5q-uc.a.run.app/xyxCIPDXZXgiR6DsjWx3yFOuXYZ4
Status
500
VersionHTTP/2
Transferred370 B (21 B size)
Referrer Policystrict-origin-when-cross-origin
Request PriorityHighest
DNS ResolutionSystem

I suspect I did something wrong concerning the CORS, but I am not confident about that.
Does any one have an idea of where the issue is, and how I can fix it ?
Further information.
Here is the kind of local code I use to call the cloud function handleUserIn :
const handleUserIn = (usrid:string) => {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const fnUrl = "https://handleuserin-abc3du7e9q-uc.a.run.app/" + usrid
  xhr.open("GET", fnUrl);
  xhr.send();
} /* End of handleUserIn */

And I do something similar to call handleUserOut.

Why are you trying to set cors headers manually in your function when you've already delegated that responsibility to the Firebase SDK with {cors: ["*"]}?

Well, I tried quite a number of changes in my code, without getting something both working and with no error. If I understand your comment handleUserIn should work. Am I wrong ? But it also produces an error. Or tell me what I need to change please.

It's also very weird that you're choosing to serialize an object as JSON, then immediately deserialize it again.  That doesn't seem to serve any purpose.  What is element 0 supposed to be? What are you passing in from the client side?  Please edit the question showing all relevant code so that we could duplicate the issue ourselves.  We can only know what "wrong behavior" is if you fully explain what you expect the code to do, and provide all of it.

@Doug. Sorry, this way of writing the code may not be the best. It is probably not even good. I am ready to get advice.
But it is one way that worked after many trials and errors. What I am passing from the client side is just a user id.
I have edited the post to clarify things up.

What happens if you remove all the JSON stuff and try to use request.params as it's documented?  Also I suggest using response.send as it's documented.  The number 0 doesn't seem to be a meaningful response.

@Doug. I followed your suggestions. And modified my post accordingly. The first makes the code cleaner. It is your second tip about response.send, that made the original error (reason for my post) disapear. In case you care about it, and shape your tips as an answer, I will be glad to accept it.

If so, I may have to reverse my edit and put response.send(0) back into my post to show the error I was making.

Firstly, I suggest removing the use of JSON.stringify and JSON.parse.  They aren't adding any value here.
You were (before the edit) sending a response to the client like this:
response.send(0);

The number 0 isn't a rational response understood by Express.  You should send an actual HTTP status code to the caller indicating the level of success or failure from your function.  See the documentation for response.send().
